# Editing elementor Menu Cart

Tags: wordpress, menu, cart, elementor

I have a wordpress site and i am using Elementor . I have used "Menu cart" to display the cart content.
[Cart_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbZ0K.png)

Now i am trying to remove "Remove Item Icon" (small cross next to product) on the cart. But if i am disabling it through setting , it is getting removed for all products. Instead i just want to remove for one item.

[Item_to_be_removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlxfm.png)

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: So you want to remove it within 1 product only?

Comment: My requirement is to not to be able to remove one particular product . If you see in the second screenshot i have marked the element whose "remove icon" i want to remove. For example we have category 1 and category 2 . So if user is adding both category 1 and 2 in cart , the user should not be able to remove category 2.

Comment: As a fast solution I have code which will disable product remove from cart but not the icon. For the icon its takes a longer time.

Comment: okkk . I suppose that should work . I can get some idea out of it and can improvise to work on the icon.

Comment: try my answer and let me know if it helped you

Comment: I suspect , we will have to use elementor hook as it is mini cart where we need to disable remove icon and not the woo commerce cart page . I have already disabled in woo commerce cart page . But still let me try using it and will let you know the result

Comment: The code Ive provided will not let you remove it from elementor mini cart, icon will be there but you will be not allowed to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to add filter with woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link.

```
function disable_remove_for_sim_card( $cart_item_key, $button_link ){
    $product_id = 'ID'; //your product ID here
    $cart_item = WC()->cart->get_cart()[$cart_item_key];
    
    if( in_array($cart_item['data']->get_id(), $product_id) )
        $button_link = '';

    return $button_link;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 'disable_remove_for_sim_card');
```

Ideas how to disable elementors minicart button is maybe to set a extra class into cart item when it has its ID in array and add some css class to hide it.